# Wordpress landing.php page: access my plugin then redirect

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I need to create a static php landing page (landing.php) for inbound advertiser links that that can access my wp plugin and then redirect to homepage.
Is it possible to access my plugin from a "regular" .php file? If so, how?
Or is there better way to do this within WP that doesn't load templates and just accesses my wp plugin and redirects to homepage?

Comment: what do mean by "regular" php file? you mean one without the wordpress loop? you know you can create a "blank page" connect to a page within wordpress and use your plugin and then redirect to your home page

Comment: yes, without the wordpress loop.
Could you elaborate on the "blank page" redirect? Sounds like what I'm looking for. I really don't much about WP. I just jumped write into plugin stuff.

Comment: may i ask what your plugin does?

Comment: It just checks referer and/or querystring and looks up data based on referer domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this line at the top of your landing php:

```
require('/path/to/wp-load.php');
```

After that, you can use all WordPress functions, including your plugin.

Comment: Thats the quick and easy and not correct way of doing it in wordpress please read this [**entry**](http://ottopress.com/2010/dont-include-wp-load-please/) by ottopress and inside wordpress documentation itself read [**here**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website)